# Drag div to another part of the text

Tags: javascript, html, position

I have a html file with the following code:

```
<style>
    .important {
        border: solid;
        ...
    }
</style>

<body>

    Lorem ipsum 1<br/>
    <div class="important">
        Lorem Ipsum 2
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum 3<br/>
    Lorem ipsum 4

</body>
```

User needs to be able to reposition the `<div>` with class="important" if he prefers it under or above where it is.

So, we have:

```
Lorem Ipsum 1
Lorem Ipsum 2 // with class="important"
Lorem Ipsum 3
Lorem Ipsum 4
```

and user must be able to "drag" (not necessarily drag, although it would be the best) the Lorem Ipsum 2 up and down, so it would be:

```
Lorem Ipsum 1
Lorem Ipsum 3
Lorem Ipsum 2 // with class="important"
Lorem Ipsum 4
```

or

```
Lorem Ipsum 2 // with class="important"
Lorem Ipsum 1
Lorem Ipsum 3
Lorem Ipsum 4
```

It may be more than one line at a time (usually is). The idea is that Lorem Ipsum 2 is a "THIS IS IMPORTANT" box. User is editing content for other users.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but in the database this "important" parts are tagged this way

```
Lorem Ipsum 1
[[!]]Lorem Ipsum 2[[/!]]
Lorem Ipsum 3
Lorem Ipsum 4
```

So, there are some questions:

1) is it possible to that with drag and drop?

2) how will the "new position" be passed to my script? It cannot be X and Y, because I need it in relation to the text (as the database text will be modified)

3) is there a better way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think jQueryUI's draggable is what you need:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

Comment: I'll take a look. any ideas on a non-jquery way?

Comment: HTML5 has got some standard events related with dragging objects, but you still need to use some javascript. Check this:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp